# Incorrect binary search output

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with this binary search on an array. It runs but I get the incorrect output each time. I'm not too sure why. If anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class chapter7Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] numbers = {1, 566, 18, 1, 8, 5, 18, 4, 3, 8};
        int searchValue;
        int foundValue;

        System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
        searchValue = scanner.nextInt();

        foundValue = searchMethod(numbers, searchValue);

        if (value == -1) {
            System.out.println("Didn't find the value.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("found the value.");
        }
    }

    // Here's the search method used to pass the array and the scanner 
    // input into it
    public static int thisMethod(int[] array, int value) {
        int middle;
        int first = 0;
        int last = array.length - 1;
        int position = -1;
        boolean found = false;

        while (!found && first < = last) {

            middle = (first + last) / 2;
            if (array[middle] == value) {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
            } else if (array[middle] > value) {
                last = middle - 1;
            } else {
                first = middle + 1;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: For binary search, first you have to sort the array.

Comment: Sort the array and try

Comment: Binary search works when the array or list is sorted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, for binary search implementation we need a sorted array. So you need to sort your array first by using following code snippet

```
private static void sortArray(int[] array){
        int temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if (array[j] < array [j - 1]) {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Call this method before calling binary search method as below

```
sortArray(numbers);
foundValue = searchMethod(numbers,searchValue );
```

You will have the exact answer.
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned, you need to sort it first. This code should work, don't forget the import statement at the top.

```
    import java.util.Arrays; 

    public class chapter7Assignment{
    
        public static void main(String[] args){
       
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       
          int[] numbers = {1,566,18,1,8,5,18,4,3,8};
          int searchValue;
          int foundValue;
       
          System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
          searchValue = scanner.nextInt();

          // Sort in ascending order
          Arrays.sort(numbers);
       
          foundValue = searchMethod(numbers,searchValue );
          
          if(value == -1){
             System.out.println("Didn't find the value.");
          }else{
             System.out.println("found the value.");
          }
       }
       
       // Here's the search method used to pass the array and the scanner 
       // input into it
       public static int thisMethod (int [] array, int value){
          int middle;
          int first= 0;
          int last = array.length -1;
          int position = -1;
          boolean found = false;
       
       
          while(!found && first <= last){
          
          
             middle = (first + last) / 2;
             if(array[middle] == value){
                found = true;
                position = middle;
             }
             else if(array[middle] > value){
                last = middle -1;
             }else{
                first = middle + 1;
             }
             
         }     
         
         return position;       
        }
    }
}
```